# Need cheap source control

Tags: php, svn

My friend and I accepted simple PHP job, he has some experience working with a small team of developers and I'm new to this (and PHP to be honest :).
When I asked him about his environment I found out they (he and his previous team) never used source control, just a shared FTP server with a lot of mess. Now beginning this project I want to do it properly and use source control, I did some research and it looks like SVN is the simplest to use and fits our simple requirements.

My problem is that I don't really have an extra box to create a server... I have two options, one is to use my main windows machine as a server (it's always on so that's not a problem) BUT I can't always guarantee that it will be on when I'm far from home and I don't like how it will waste CPU cycles (It's also my gaming rig), the other option is to use an old laptop I have lying around (a Pentium 3 with about 128-256MB of RAM) and install the slimmest version of linux on it and the SVN server. it has the advantage of being simple, cheap and easy to maintain, but it has the disadvantage of being alow performing old laptop and having some uncertainty about it's reliability (I guess I'll set up some backup to my main machine).

Which option is better? I would prefer using the laptop but I'm unsure if its specs will slow us down, if I do use it, what version of linux would you recommend, and how simple is it to add some regular backup to it (I have almost no linux experience but I'm glad to learn).

PS. forgot to mention, both of us developing on windows machines.

**EDIT:** Most of you recommend Git and Mercurial, I think I'll go with mercurial because I read that git is more complicated, I really want the simplest solution that I can find. Unless git has some major advantage over mercurial? or maybe mercurial is the better one for the job?

Comment: Just google for free SVN hosting.  You'll get even more options if you open it up to git and mercurial.

Answer (score 2):

Look at distributed version control systems like [git](http://git-scm.com/) and [Mercurial (hg)](http://mercurial.selenic.com/). Both have free/cheap hosting services (e.g., http://www.github.com and http://www.bitbucket.org) and are well suited for multiple developers working independently.

Also both have good tooling on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/)/mercurial (`hg`)? You can set up (apparently) free private depots. Mercurial is crazy easy to use and is a lot newer (and *rapidly* gaining popularity) than svn.

Comment: +1 for Mercurial.  You can also use Kiln for free for one or two person teams, which integrates with fogbugz.  http://www.fogcreek.com/kiln/StudentAndStartup.html

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) (hg) as mentioned above, simple, easy to use and distributed. Personally, I prefer it slightly to [Git](http://git-scm.com/) and secondly its Windows support is better.

[Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) also lets you have free private repositories whereas [Github](https://github.com/) is only free for public repos. Which I am guessing will be a factor if you are producing commercial code.

Answer (score 1):

Use git.  It was designed and written by the guy who started Linux and he knows what he's doing.

You don't need a server for git, each user has a copy of the whole repository and you sync to each other. There is a bit of a learning curve, but if you're smart it will make you better developers.

Answer (score 1):

DVCS like git is cool because you do not even need server. You basically just "synchronise" your code between each other here and there and due to fact that each repository has data from all repositories once is "synchronised" you do not need extra backup or server in most cases.

I found nice feature whit git (probably whit other VCS-s too) is that since they are just file based you can use any (free) cloud storage / ftp / git_server to backup your files in case of cataclysmic catastrophe.

Answer (score 0):

Why not go another route and get GitHub.com (pretty cheap, but costs a little) or BitBucket.com (this one is free for up to 5 users and unlimited repositories).  You'll avoid a lot of headaches from maintaining your own servers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to host it yourself, check out [subversion edge](http://www.open.collab.net/go/csvne2_r2a/). Its a packaged svn that comes with apache and some management tools.

If you dont want to deal with admin stuff, check out [beanstalk](http://beanstalkapp.com/). They do hosted SVN.

Or, you could use something like git and github; but if you're really set on svn, check out beanstalk